# Lazy AdMob ads loading

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

I'm loading a simple banner ad in my main activity. The problem is whenever I start application it stucks about 2 sec on white screen and then loads UI. 
The problem isn't about the app code, because before I added ads app used to launch instantly. This is the code I load ads:
in `onCreate`:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-#######")
        val mAdView: AdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)
        mAdView.visibility = View.GONE
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        val adView = AdView(this)
        adView.adSize = AdSize.BANNER
        adView.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"  <- test id
        initializeAds(mAdView, adRequest)
```

`initializeAds()`:

```
 fun initializeAds(adView: AdView, adRequest: AdRequest){
        adView.loadAd(adRequest)
        adView.adListener = object : AdListener(){
            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded()
                if (adView.visibility == View.GONE) {
                    adView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: Int) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(p0)
                adView.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to load ad without UI lag?

Comment: Are you sure that you use test ad unit ID for Android baners?

Comment: I've already used unit ID generated from AdMob to push app to Play Store

Comment: But for testing you should use test ad unit ID.

Comment: I updated code few hours ago,  it does run slowly anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay guys, finally I found a quick workaround. I found `MobileAds.initialize(context, id)` and `AdRequest.Builder().build()` as making lag. Obviously activity won't be fully loaded unless `onCreate` is fully executed. To bypass that I used `Handler` to delay `MobileAds.initialize` and `AdRequest.Builder().build` and then it doesn't make UI lag. This is my updated code:

```
       // we can't delay UI tasks so we need initialize adView here - it's not heavy task anyway
        val mAdView: AdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)
        mAdView.visibility = View.GONE

        //delay ads to be displayed 2 sec after Activity is loaded
        Handler().postDelayed({
            MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713")
            initializeAds(mAdView)
        }, 2000)
```

`initializeAds(AdView)`:

```
   fun initializeAds(adView: AdView) {
        adView.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        adView.adListener = object : AdListener() {
            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded()
                //if ad is loaded just show it
                if (adView.visibility == View.GONE) {
                    adView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: Int) {
                //if we can't show ad just hide it
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(p0)
                adView.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope it will help if anybody is struggling with alike problem

Answer (score 2):

Use this as banner ad id `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`

Comment: Context: The [docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner) mention using that ID for test ads.

Comment: even though using test id my app loads slowly.

Answer (score 2):

Domin is suggesting that you do a post delay of approx 2000ms for MobileAds.Initialize(). Please don't do that. After the 2secs the UI just freezes! The user will get super annoyed. It's better if the startup was slower than the app being non-responsive just when the user starts using it.

Comment: The freezing duration will be like 500ms tested by my phone. It is annoyed for sure.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Kotlin Code
//Heavy tasks in Second Thread
//finally loadAd() in UI thread
Thread{
MobileAds.initialize(this);
val mAdView = findViewById<AdView>(R.id.adview);
val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build();
runOnUiThread {
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);     
}}.start();
```

Comment: In general it's bad idea to use raw threads like that in android - activity may be destroyed before background thread is done.